# C# saving multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I've been working on a C# XNA game for a while and am just getting around to the saving/loading functions. I have a long list of arrays with various information in that need to be saved and loaded.

I'm wondering what the best process for doing this would be? I was looking at protobuf but the array which contains all the tile data is multidimensional in the following format Tile[z,x,y]. I am able to save this using binaryformatter but it comes out at over 350mb and takes upwards of 2 minutes. I have also tried writing it out using streamwriter which is much faster but uses about as much disk space. Any suggestions on how best to proceed?

Comment: **Compression**, if you want to save disk space. Keep StreamWriter but use it together with System.IO.Compression classes. You may try (but it depends what kind of data you have) to store it as a **sparse file** (but this flag can't be set from .NET so you have to go back to native CreateFile function). If you let OS do it for you then you won't need special code to handle that (and it'll be much much faster). Oh BTW if it's Tile[,,] and not Tile[][][] then you may even consider to do a raw **memory dump** (sequential access to Tile[,,] is slower than Tile[][][]).

Comment: why don't you try to use some kind of database, i don't think reading from files is worth when you have so much of db

Comment: What sort of data does a Tile contain? Is it necessary to save all of it, or can some fields/properties be calculated from other fields? Is your array 'sparse' or are most coordinates occupied?

Comment: Finally, do you need more speed? If thread synchronization isn't an issue you may do it with **async IO**. It won't be faster but your app won't need to wait IO to complete. Of course you may put everything together: compressed stream with asynchronous I/O (it's not the same as writing done in another thread) to a sparse file (I did forget to mention it's supported only for NTFS).

Comment: Thanks for this, ill take a look at compression, the speed isn't bad its the file size which is a concern, ideally wanted it below 50mb. Would you recommend changing it to a jagged array for this or leaving as is?

Comment: If you do not have any (measured) performance issue...you may keep it as it is. IMO they're implementation details that may change tomorrow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a lot of zeros in your tile-array, so you can think about more efficient ways to store it.

One way could be to save tubles: (x, y, z, value). This more efficient if 75% or more of your tiles are zero, another solution is to use compression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, none of the tiles will be zero but I do have some ideas of how to save them more efficiently. I think compression is going to be the best way to go with this.